# Create an agent calculator

Tags: java, agents-jade

I want to create an agent to calculate the sum of the whole set parameters

```
import jade.core.Agent;

public class Somme extends Agent {
//  String argstrings [];
    int Som=0;
    protected void setup(){
        Object args [] = getArguments();
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            String argstrings = args[i].toString();
            Som = Som + Integer.parseInt(argstrings);
            System.out.println(Som);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the type from object to String and from String to Integer?

Comment: Um, exactly like you're doing it (other than you shouldn't start a variable name with a capital letter)? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Your loop IS calculating the sum.  You are converting from strings to ints.  What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
int j = Integer.parseInt( (String) args[0] );
```